# How to assign values to a tensor by index?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a 2D tensor, the shape is (M,N). And I want to get a mask that for each row, the top-k of the given tensor is 1, and others as 0.
For example, the tensor is:

```
[[1,3,5,7],
 [2,4,7,0],
 [9,3,1,5]]
```

If set the topk as 1, the mask should be:

```
[[0,0,0,1],
 [0,0,1,0],
 [1,0,0,0]]
```

If set the topk as 2, the mask should be:

```
[[0,0,1,1],
 [0,1,1,0],
 [1,0,0,1]]
```

I figure out a very tedious method:

```
_, nn_idx = tf.nn.top_k(tmp, top_k)  # the shape of tmp is (M,N) and the shape of nn_idx is (M,top_k)
nn_idx_one = tf.reshape(nn_idx, [-1, 1])
nn_idx_multi_hot = tf.one_hot(nn_idx_one, depth=N)  # (M*top_k,1) -> (M*top_k,N), N is about 100000 (very big)
nn_idx_multi_hot = tf.reshape(nn_idx_multi_hot, [-1, top_k, N])  # (M,top_k,N)
nn_idx_multi_hot = tf.reduce_sum(nn_idx_multi_hot, axis=1)  # (M,N) 
mask_a = tf.ones(shape=[M, N])
mask_b = tf.zeros(shape=[M, N])
mask = tf.where(nn_idx_multi_hot > 0, mask_a , mask_b )  # the target mask
```

This operation is heavily memory consumption, I think there is a concise way to do this, can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with [`tf.scatter_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd) like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

tf.random.set_seed(0)
tmp = tf.random.uniform((3, 4), 0, 10, dtype=tf.int32)
top_k = 2
tf.print(tmp)
# [[3 9 1 7]
#  [7 4 0 9]
#  [6 6 0 7]]
_, nn_idx = tf.nn.top_k(tmp, top_k)
s = tf.shape(tmp, out_type=nn_idx.dtype)
row_idx = tf.repeat(tf.range(s[0]), top_k)
ones_idx = tf.stack([row_idx, tf.reshape(nn_idx, [-1])], axis=1)
res = tf.scatter_nd(ones_idx, tf.ones(s[0] * top_k, tmp.dtype), s)
tf.print(res)
# [[0 1 0 1]
#  [1 0 0 1]
#  [1 0 0 1]]
```

EDIT: For 1.x versions, with graph mode and without `tf.repeat`, the following is equivalent:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.set_random_seed(0)
    tmp = tf.random_uniform((3, 4), 0, 10, dtype=tf.int32)
    top_k = 2
    _, nn_idx = tf.nn.top_k(tmp, top_k)
    s = tf.shape(tmp, out_type=nn_idx.dtype)
    row_idx = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(tf.range(s[0]), 1), (1, top_k))
    ones_idx = tf.stack([tf.reshape(row_idx, [-1]),
                         tf.reshape(nn_idx, [-1])], axis=1)
    res = tf.scatter_nd(ones_idx, tf.ones(s[0] * top_k, tmp.dtype), s)
    tmp_val, res_val = sess.run((tmp, res))
    print(tmp_val)
    # [[2 4 8 2]
    #  [4 8 7 5]
    #  [1 9 8 8]]
    print(res_val)
    # [[0 1 1 0]
    #  [0 1 1 0]
    #  [0 1 1 0]]
```

Comment: I really appreciate your timely help. But my tensorflow version is 1.11.0(sorry I didn't mention it earlier). Could you please give the low-version solution? Thanks.

Comment: @lidaiye I added a 1.x version that hopefully should work for you.